# What is this formula involving circles trying to do?

Tags: variables, math, formula, geometry, ambiguous

```
x, y, z = pos
radius = width / 2.0
if width >= 0.0:
    x = -x
a = radius * math.pi
a = (x/a) * math.pi
```

This is a code snippet from someone other than me, and I've been wanting to understand it. However, the variable `a` is a little ambiguous, and I'm having trouble figuring out its purpose.

This snippet is part of a function that calculates an arch that text will be displayed over.

The variable `pos` is the position of the current letter we are working with.
The variable `width` is the width of the entire line.

Comment: I wouldn't say 'a' was ambiguous - it's x/radius. Doesn't mean I have a clue what it's for though :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nonsense usage of math.pi - result doesn't depend on it.
`a = x/R = Cos(Fi)`, where Fi is direction angle of (coordinate origin - starting point) vector, if R is radius of arc with origin as center

(Cos(Fi) negated for positive width values)